# Should the “c++” tag start to imply C++11 by default?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

2 years ago this was asked: [When did the "c++" tag start to imply C++11 by default?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112641/when-did-the-c-tag-start-to-imply-c11-by-default)

1 year ago this was asked: [When submitting an answer, when is it ok to use C++11?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133642/when-submitting-an-answer-when-is-it-ok-to-use-c11)

Many questions are tagged just `C++` and not `C++11`, but the accepted answer uses `C++11` features.

Now that `C++14` is around the corner, and `C++11` is the defacto standard version:

Is it finally time to stop expecting the `C++11` tag if acceptable answers can use `C++11` features?  Or even if the question includes `C++11` features?

Should the `C++11` tag be depricated (until C++14 becomes generally adopted) and **not** request: "Please tag questions about C++11 with the C++ tag, along with the C++11 tag."

Should the `C++03` tag be expected to be used to denote questions where C++11 features should not be used in an answer? And state something like, **"Please use this tag if the current standard C++11 features cannot be used"**

*Unlike some other programming languages it is not clear from the question if C++11 features can be used in the answer and in fact some answers may include them and others may not*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the guidelines for using version-specific tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/what-are-the-guidelines-for-using-version-specific-tags)

Comment: Having said that, I think Jeff's attitude there was pretty severe. We routinely tag `async` C# questions with the `C#` tag (because, y'know, C#), and with the `C#-5.0` tag because C# 5.0 is required to use `async`.  We also tag questions with, say, `.NET-3.5`, if the question asker is confined to using a version of the .NET Framework no higher than that (it happens).

Comment: @RobertHarvey - this is not asking which tag to use, but rather, asking if a tag change is warrented at this time

Comment: I didn't provide some relevant guidance?  OK, then let me spell it out: *no, a change is not required.*  In the same manner that C# is used generically to refer to all C# questions, C++ should be used generically to refer to all things C++, and a version-specific tag should be added if that's appropriate.

Comment: Note that old questions that were asked before C++11 came out would no longer make sense if the meaning of the C++ tag changed with the times.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but it seems the meaning of the C++ tag has changed, as answers today include C++11 features, where they did not before, in your linked question, version specific tags are used to denote older versions, not to denote the current version

Comment: As I said, I don't completely agree with the philosophy espoused there.  C#-5.0 is a perfectly valid tag, used in the manner I described above.  It also happens to be the current version.  If a C++ question asks about C++14 specific features, I think the question should have both tags.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - editted question and I expect use of the C++14 tag soon (once it is created)

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Robert made the point very well and I think there is a pretty site-wide consensus about it (only version with version tags if you're confined to a specific version). Personally, when dealing with versions in transition I try to offer an 'old' (C++03 in this case) answer and a new (C++11 in this case) answer - I'd also go on answers with an "older" answer and suggest a new version (in an answer or a comment) one if it's considerably better.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say that the C++11 tag should be "retired?"  *All* version-specific tags should state (or imply) "please use this tag only when discussing issues unique to this version."

Comment: @Charles editted to say depricated as it is currently redundant

Comment: Okay, let me try to tl;dr this: "C++11 is common enough that people want to begin *assuming* C++11 when answering.  There's wording in the tags that dissuades this.  Should the wording be updated, and what should the wording be updated to?"  Is that about right?

Comment: This question should be migrated to MSO.